# Find the value b such that the initial value problem has a solution where the limit $\lim_{x\to 0+} y(x)$ exists

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the value b such that the initial value problem:
>   $$y'+ \frac{y}{\tanh(x)}=2\bullet \frac{\cosh(x)}{\sinh(1)}$$
>
> $$y(1)=b$$
>   has a solution where the limit $\lim_{x\to 0+} y(x)$ exists

To be honest, I am completely blank. I tried to solve the differential equations

> $y=\frac{1}{2\bullet \sinh(1)}\bullet \frac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}{e^{2x}-e^{-2x}} + \frac{c}{e^{x}-e^{-x}}$

(not sure if I even did it correctly), but I am not sure where to go from there, or if its even necessary to integrate it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: look for a solution of the form $y = c \sinh(x)$.